# Rails 3: NoMethodError in ReviewsController#create

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a relationship user (has_many :reviews) and review ( belongs_to :user) and I'm getting a NoMethodError when I try to execute create in reviews_controller.

```
def create
   @review = @user.reviews.create(:service_id => 10)
end
```

The same query works fine in the console but it gives that error when I do it through the controller.

What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: can you add the backtrace and the contents of the objects involved? (e.g. `@user`)

Comment: Before the call to create, do a "puts @user.inspect" to verify @user contains what you think it should.

Comment: that was the problem.. I wasnt logged in.. :/ please let me accept your answer. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print out @user details to log to verify current_user is populating the value correctly.